# generating permutations using mathematica 4.0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hi I am using Mathematica 4.0. I am trying to find all the permutations, for example, say there are two numbers 0 & 1. I am trying to generate all permutations using these two numbers in 3(say) places with repetition i.e. like {1,1,1},{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{1,0,0}... Also I am trying to put each of the permutation in an array. Is there any code or command in Mathematica 4.0 by which I can do all these things. Please help me in this task...

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mathematica 5.1 and higher, there is a function `Tuples` which does what you want. You may try

```
getTuples[elements_List, length_Integer] :=
  Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ Table[elements, {length}]], length - 1]
```

For example:

```
In[6]:= getTuples[{0, 1}, 3]

Out[6]= {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

But I don't know if this works in M4.0. It should, I guess, but I can not check. Generally, you will face tons of difficulties of various kinds working with such an obsolete version as 4.0, including lacking the functionality, inferior performance and interface (front-end), certain bugs that were fixed in later versions, incompatibility with code written in later versions, and getting help. This is especially true for Mathematica given huge advances in all sorts of directions introduced since 4.0. So, if you plan to use it regularly, I'd strongly suggest to upgrade.

Comment: thanks, I have already upgraded my version to 5.2 & got my result.Now I want to put each of the permutation in a separate array like lst1={0,0,0};lst2={0,0,1}... using a loop.because if the no. of permutations become large then it will not be wise to write separate list name for each of the array. plz help me in this task

Comment: @rajib arefin:  Sorry to say it, but this is not how SO (Stack Overflow) works. Please post it as a separate question, and folks here will be happy to answer. This way, it will be indexed and useful for new users looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of archeological question :D. Version 4 is pretty old!

```
<<DiscreteMath`Combinatorica`

perm1[l_,n_]:=Union[KSubsets[Flatten[Table[l,{n}]],n]]  

In[70]:= perm1[{1,2,1},4]
Out[70]= {{1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,2},{1,1,2,1},{1,1,2,2},{1,2,1,1},
          {1,2,1,2},{1,2,2,1},{1,2,2,2},{2,1,1,1},{2,1,1,2},
          {2,1,2,1},{2,1,2,2},{2,2,1,1},{2,2,1,2},{2,2,2,1},{2,2,2,2}}  

In[73]:= perm1[{1,0},3]
Out[73]= {{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{0,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.But it does not working in Mthma4.0, showing this result :In[45]:=
perm[n_] := Permutations[Flatten[Table[{1, 0}, {n}]], {n}]

In[46]:=
perm[3]

From In[46]:=
Permutations::"argx": "\!\(Permutations\) called with \!\(2\) arguments; 1 \
argument is expected."

Out[46]=
Permutations[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {3}]

Comment: Ok I can collect mathematica 5.0. Will these code support in Mathematica 5.0 ?

Comment: @rajib Permutations was last modified in v6, so I'm not sure, because the doc I have does not state which modification was done at which version.

Comment: The solutions given by belisarius and Leonid Shifrin both work with Mma v5.2, if that is any use (installed on old Mac). No v 4.0, though.

Comment: @TomD Your museum is amazing :D

Comment: @belisarius It is even more amazing.  Found an old imac that no one has used for years, went out bought a bag of coal, shovelled it in and got Mma v4.2 running ;).  Both solutions worked exactly as described without any problems

Comment: I have already upgraded my version to 5.2 & got my result.Now I want to put each of the permutation in a separate array like lst1={0,0,0};lst2={0,0,1}... using a loop.because if the no. of permutations become large then it will not be wise to write separate list name for each of the array. plz help me in this task

Answer (score 0):

Just an aside - please note that documentation for all previous versions of Mathematica is freely available online at http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy - specifically for version 4, see http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4.

You can search the v4 docs via google:

permutations site:reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4

which turns up the v4 function Permutations http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/Permutations.html which has examples and a few links to other parts of the old Mathematica Book.

Comment: Permutations in V4 didn't do what the OP wants. It was later modified, and now you could just say `Permutations[{1,0},3]` ... but it was not available at that time.